# Why UI is freezing During WPF DataGrid Binding?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, binding, .net-4.0, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` with some `DataGridTemplateColumn` ,complicated `Binding Converter` and some `Style DataTrigger` and bind some rows from `EntityFramework` model to `DataGrid ItemsSource` in code behind .

The problem is: during the `Binding` process the `UI` is freezing until the `DataGrid ItemContainerGenerator`  state change to `ContainersGenerated`, so what is the solution??

Comment: How many items do you have in your DataGrid?

Comment: About 200 items but the binding process done after 3 seconds while the UI is freezing!

Comment: Thats not binding process that is generating all items in DataGrid. I suggest you to enable virtualization.

Comment: According to [This Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.enablerowvirtualization.aspx) `To improve performance, the EnableRowVirtualization property is set to true by default.`

Comment: Verify that. But my bet is that your converter is hanging up somewhere. Have you stepped through it to see if it's flowing through? Maybe post your Converter logic here?

Comment: I think the problem is in `Binding` process because the converters was done its job in times less than seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting the data of the grid at Background priority. This should improve the responsiveness until you can work out if anything else requires optimisation.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(p => this.GridDataItemsSource = data, DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

If your mixture of converters, triggers etc is slowing down the appearance of the data in the grid when applied as one big lump, try initially setting the grid to an empty collection of your line items and then inserting line items one by one into the grid using the Dispatcher on BackgroundPriority

```
this.GridDataItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<MyLineItems();
foreach(var item in _lineItems)
{
   Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(_ => this.GridDataItemsSource.Add(item), DispatcherPriority.Background);
}
```

The effect should be to see the grid being updated quite quickly with each new item and your view should stay responsive.

Comment: This way we can fetch the data from data source in background thread but after completion of this process the UI still freezing until all items bind to DataGrid and the DataGrid ItemContainerGenerator state change to ContainersGenerated

Comment: No. I meant fetch the data on a background thread and then set the bound data property using the Dispatcher on BackgroundPriority.

Comment: Nice job @Mark, but in second solution for each item addition the height of scrollbar changed until reaches to final height, so how you solve this problem?

Comment: There is a possible issue, that if the message gets delayed, the grid will add a wrong item. Create a reference of the function to call, and place the item as a param, like this:

this.GridDataItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<MyLineItems();
var del = (Action<MyLineItems>)this.GridDataItemsSource.Add;
foreach(var item in _lineItems)
{
   Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(del, DispatcherPriority.Background, item);
}

Also, if you are calling from the UI thread, use beginInvoke so the UI is still free to handle other messages.

Answer (score 1):

To improve performance, the EnableRowVirtualization property is set to true by default. When the EnableRowVirtualization property is set to true, the DataGrid does not instantiate a DataGridRow object for each data item in the bound data source. Instead, the DataGrid creates DataGridRow objects only when they are needed, and reuses them as much as it can. For example, the DataGrid creates a DataGridRow object for each data item that is currently in view and recycles the row when it scrolls out of view.

Instead of hoping it is true by default just set it to true yourself or even to false to see the difference.

In case you load content from database on first time your collection of items property is being invoked then you don't have to wonder that it runs slow. It takes a while till all data has been transfered from database to your ViewModel.

Anyways I will drop few links here for you that might help you out.

To improve performance read those tips:

http://wpftutorial.net/10PerformanceTips.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613546.aspx

Comment: Any way we must improve the performance but how con solve UI Freeze?

Comment: I have another good hint for you. Only ask questions like "how can I solve UI Freeze" when you posted code. Only code will give as an exact peek of what you up to. So post code and then we will find a way to solve your issue.